# Which font family to use in PSD to HTML stylesheet (Hiragino Sans GB W3)

Tags: css

A friend ask me to convert a PSD design to HTML, in the PSD design he is using the font: Hiragino Sans GB W3.

Then in stylesheet im using font-family:

```
@font-face {

  font-family: "Hiragino Sans GB W3";

}

body {

  font-family: "Hiragino Sans GB W3";

}
```

But he told me the the font doesnt look like the PSD design, what can I do to improve my stylesheet to use the "Hiragino Sans GB W3" in a right way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for an alternative font that's already installed on every system, because you can only use installed fonts - sounds logic.

But with the features of HTML5 you can use nearly every font if you have the rights to. I recommend you looking through [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts).

It's even possible to provide some "fallbacks".

```
selector {
    font-family: "Some Exotic Font", "Not so exotic", "Arial", sans-serif;
}
```

The Browser will search for `"Some Exotic Font"` and if it can't finds the font it will look for `"Some Exotic Font"` and so on till `sans-serif`(or `serif` if you want a serif font).

If that still does not satisfy you, you can even convert the text into an image and include the image instead of the text. But that is some ***very bad*** practice.

Comment: I think i found a decent solution: font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Hiragino Sans GB", "Hiragino Sans GB W3", "Microsoft YaHei", sans-serif;

Comment: It has to be a widely supported font. The Hirago family, as an example, is not. You'll have to define fallbacks.

Comment: @JoséPabloOrozcoMarín could you explain the "Hiragino Sans GB W3" part? shouldn't just "Hiragino Sans GB" be enough?

Comment: Dude... This is _old_. It seems like the Higarino Family has different Types named similarily. I suppose that `W3` is just a variant of the normal `Hiragino Sans GB`. If he explicitly wants to use this variant, he has to include the `W3`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use fontsquirrel http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to upload your font file which converts it to all common different browsers.